# cryptocurrency historic data in fine granularity, e.g. minute bars

Tags: api, historical

For daily OHLC data, I'm aware of all the wonderful resources on Quandl. But is there a good minute bar database for couple of the major cryptocurrencies, e.g. bitcoin, ether, etc. I don't need very long history, just couple of months of minute-interval pricing would be good enough for me.

A related question. To pull live data from the various exchanges, I'm aware of cryptocompare's API

https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-data-price-

Is there any similar APIs out there?

Comment: checkout https://coinograph.io it provides historical and live API crypto market data for multiple exchanges. Disclaimer: I've made it